# add keys to array and group values

Tags: php, arrays

I have simple array:

```
Array(1,3,c,4,a,24,m,4)
```

I need to group the two values for the key like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 - 3
    [1] => c - 4
    [2] => a - 24
    [3] => m - 4
)
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do lists/requirements.

Comment: [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) with a size of 2; then [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with a callback that [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)s on ' - ';

Comment: @Mark Baker  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Concise solution with `foreach` loop and `array_values` function:

```
$arr = [1,3,'c',4,'a',24,'m',4];
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    ($k % 2 == 0)? $result[$k] = $v : $result[$k-1] .= " - $v";
}

var_dump(array_values($result));

// the output:
array (size=4)
  0 => string '1 - 3' (length=5)
  1 => string 'c - 4' (length=5)
  2 => string 'a - 24' (length=6)
  3 => string 'm - 4' (length=5)
```